# String matching irrespective of some character like in R

Tags: r

I want to match `vishal - kumar - chaudhary` with `vishal kumar chaudhary`.

Can anyone help me to ignore `-` or `.` while matching?

Comment: Remove `-` or `.` with `gsub` ?

Comment: i don't know gsub can you suggest the code of gsub

Comment: the string is dynamic i cann't edit the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `gsub` you can remove unwanted characters in the string and then compare both the strings.

```
string1 <- "vishal - kumar - chaudhary"
string2 <- "vishal kumar chaudhary"

stringr::str_squish(gsub('[-.]', '', string1)) == string2
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Or without `stringr::str_squish`: `gsub(" +", " ", gsub('[-.]', '', string1)) == string2`

Comment: `str_squish(gsub('[-.]', '', "61300 · Corp Taxes - CA"))` is not removing `.`

Comment: Use `gsub('[-.·]', '', "61300 · Corp Taxes - CA")`

Comment: @vishal Yes, that is different from `"."` You can include the characters that you want to exclude in `[]`.